# Image will not centre with layout manager

Tags: layout, jpanel, jlabel, jtextfield, border-layout

[image: Output]
My background image will not centre. I'm using BorderLayout.CENTER. Everything else is in the right position except for the background image which instead of being centred is a tad bit to the left. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

```
private JTextField tf;
private JLabel jl2;

   public void window() {
       ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("hangman.png");
      JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame();
      JPanel jp = new JPanel();
      JPanel jpLets = new JPanel();
      JPanel jpBlank = new JPanel();
      JPanel blankLet = new JPanel();
      JPanel imgPane = new JPanel();
      JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
      JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
      blankLet.setLayout(new BoxLayout(blankLet, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
      panel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      imgPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      panel1.setOpaque(false);//!!
     //jp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(""));
      tf = new JTextField(1);
      JLabel img = new JLabel(ic, JLabel.CENTER);
      JLabel jl = new JLabel("Enter a letter", JLabel.CENTER);
      jl2 = new JLabel("Letters used:  ", JLabel.CENTER);
      JLabel jl3 = new JLabel("__ ", JLabel.CENTER);
      jl.setFont(new Font("Rockwell", Font.PLAIN, 20));
      tf.setFont(new Font("Rockwell", Font.PLAIN, 20));
      jl2.setFont(new Font("Rockwell", Font.PLAIN, 20));
      imgPane.add(img);
      jp.add(jl);
      jp.add(tf);
      jpLets.add(jl2);
      jpBlank.add(jl3);
      blankLet.add(jpLets);
      blankLet.add(jpBlank);
      panel1.add(imgPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      panel1.add(jp, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      panel1.add(blankLet, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      panel2.add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      gameFrame.setTitle("Hangman");
      gameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      gameFrame.setIconImage(
      new ImageIcon("Hangman-Game-grey.png").getImage());
      gameFrame.setResizable(false);
      gameFrame.add(panel2);
      gameFrame.setSize(600, 600);
      gameFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      gameFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Please show  picture of your output if you are able to

Comment: picture of output was added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things you can try

1. Remove the BorderLayout from this `imgPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());`
2. If one doesn't work try to add the label to the Panel instead of the `imgPane`

   ```
   panel1.add(img, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   ```
3. Also, panel2 looks unnecessary. Get rid of that and just add panel1 to the frame
4. Try setting the alignment

   ```
   img.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
   img.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

   panel1.add(img, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   ```

Here's the code I used to reconstruct the desired result

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class HangManAlign extends JPanel {

    public HangManAlign() {
        JLabel guess = new JLabel("Guess");
        JTextField jtfGuess = new JTextField(3);

        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images/Xpo9R.png"));

        JLabel bottom = new JLabel("Letters Used                __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __");
        bottom.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.add(guess);
        topPanel.add(jtfGuess);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));

    }

    public static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new HangManAlign());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(500, 500);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

I Copied your entire image and cut it down to size, so you can see that it's centered.  Here's the image I used

[image]

Comment: No luck. Still being displayed to the left. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at my code. I reproduced a Simpler view-only version so you can see what I mean

Comment: Also, `panel2` looks unnecessary. Get rid of that and just add `panel1` to the frame.

Comment: Why does the images size make a difference when it is a png file? Shouldn't it be centred as long as it fits the JFrame?

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference. I just made it smaller than the frame size so that you can see that it's centered (with just the above code). I didn't have to align anything. You should really try to get rid of unnecessary panels. Not everything needs its own panel. Add multiple components to panels when you can. It makes the code easier to maintain. I try grouping your code together. One panel should have all the component code that added to it, below it. That way you're just left with a grouping of a top panel, and a bottom panel, and your center label